How to assign a Static IP to the VM running the Synology DSM on Virtual Box
I'm new to the networking world.
I managed to install ARK Loader and DSM on a virtual box VM.
The problem is, how do I set a static IP address to that VM? The host has set a static IP address 192.168.56.xxx, but if I set static IP address to the host-only adapter then when I boot up the VM it gets a different IP address. I tried with the virtual box DHCP enabled and disabled and it's the same: it's not getting the static IP address. I tried NAT, bridged, bridged + NAT...
Please help me understand the problem here so I can move on.

What happens if you set the IP address in DSM?
